# whoever leads s'lichos should lead the rest of the day's prayers: why s'lichos?

Tags: selichot, chazzan-prayer-leader, tefilla

*Rama* 581:1 says whoever leads *s'lichos* should lead the rest of the day's prayers, and *Magen Avraham*, followed by others including *Mishna B'rura*, says this is due to "*hamaschil b'mitzva om'rim lo g'mor*", "whoever starts fulfilling a command, we tell him to finish", and includes *shacharis*, *mincha*, and *maariv* (although *which maariv* is unclear; see *Machatzis Hashekel*). (Incidentally, *Aruch Hashulchan* notes that this was not the custom in his area at his time. In any event:)

My question is, why *s'lichos* specifically? Why don't we say, for the same reason of "*hamaschil b'mitzva...*", that whoever leads *shacharis* any day should lead the rest of the day's prayers?

**Update:** I see that the *L'vush* gives a different reason. [Apparently, in his time and place, a set *chazan* would lead *shacharis* every day, and whoever led *shacharis* on a *s'lichos* day would fast.] Thus, he writes, have the *s'lichos* leader lead *shacharis* also, instead of the usual *shacharis* leader, [and, I gather, vary the *s'lichos* leaders from day to day,] in order that no one person need to fast every day.

However, this doesn't answer my question on the *Magen Avraham* and those who quote him, who don't give that reason.

(Note also that the *L'vush*'s reason would seem not to apply nowadays, when the *s'lichos* leader does not AFAIK fast (and when we don't necessarily have the same leader daily, although many synagogues do de facto, as there is a mourner leading). But that's [another issue](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7046).)

Comment: I'm sorry, but what are Selichos?

Comment: @AdamMosheh, see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/selichot/info. This question is about the _Elul-Tishre_ ones specifically.

Comment: @msh210 - Thank you. I assume that those recited on fast days are in somewhat of a different categorization, since they don't have Ashrei preceding them.

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/117398/170

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Nit'ei Gavriel](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46450&st=&pgnum=108) (footnote 12 in the link) asks of this practice: What do we mean by המתחיל במצוה אומרים לו גמור? Aren't the following Shacharis and Mincha and (previous and/or following) Ma'ariv seperate *mitzvos*?

He answers that *s'lichos* is actually a prelude and preparation for the other *t'fillos* of the day. For example, if one says *s'lichos*, but then leaves and neglects to pray shacharis and mincha, he has not fulfilled the obligation of *s'lichos* either. It must be that the *s'lichos* are connected somehow to the other *t'fillos* of the day. (I'm not so sure about the connection to ma'ariv. It's unclear.)

According to this, the answer to your question seems pretty clear. On a regular day, each *t'filla* is a separate *mitzva*, and each can have a different *ba'al t'filla*. But on a day with *s'lichos*, the *s'lichos* are connected to the other prayers of the day. (That is, even though shacharis and mincha are seperate from each other, they are both connected to the *s'lichos* of that day.) Thus, the rule of המתחיל במצוה אומרים לו גמור becomes relevant for each seperate remaining prayer of the day.

Answer (score 2):

Althoug Ashkenazi Slichos are said before Rosh Hashana they are actually prayers for [Aseret Yemi Tshuva](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten_Days_of_Repentance). The days Slichos are said before Rosh Hashana are to make up for the 4 days missing from the ten.

That being the case this Minhag, keeping "*hamaschil...*", would just be another special Minhag that was Noheg only during these ten days. Keeping a Minhag for only ten days is itself a Minhag. I recall that one example is the refraining from [Pat Akum](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%AA_%D7%A2%D7%9B%D7%95%22%D7%9D) even if one does not hold that stringency all year.

Comment: So your answer is that keeping "_hamaschil..._" at this time is an example, like keeping _pas akum_, of taking upon extra stringencies temporarily. Sounds plausible, but do you have a source for it?

Comment: No source. I figured leaving none would be sign enough that this was just my creative thinking :). After opening the MB it seems likely that the Minhag was to avoid Machloket over who would be Shliach Tzibur. The aim was to have all the days of Slichot a Shliach Tzibur accepted by the whole community. This "Maschil" Shliach took precedence over all other Chiuvs ... I think this fits in not bad with my original answer